# Is there a way to set Serilog formatter variables via appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog, appsettings

I have the following *appsettings.json* configuration:

```
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "System": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName" ],
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                    "path": "C:\\Logs\\log.json",
                    "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I am trying to configure in the above appsettings.json file would be represented in C# as something like this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .WriteTo.File(new ElasticsearchJsonFormatter(inlineFields:true, renderMessageTemplate: false), @"C:\logs\log.json")
    .CreateLogger();
```

I need to set "inlineFields" equal to true and "renderMessageTemplate" equal to false as overrides in my appsettings.json file on the ElasticsearchJsonFormatter instance. Is there a way to do that in the appsettings.json file so that I can keep my configuration out of C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked this question on GitHub: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/138

No way :(

Answer (score 2):

They added this feature in Serilog.Settings.Configuration -v 3.3.0-dev-00291.

```
Serilog__WriteTo__Console__Name=Console
Serilog__WriteTo__Console__Args__formatter__type="Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions"
Serilog__WriteTo__Console__Args__formatter__template="[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3} {Coalesce(SourceContext, '<none>')}] {@m}\n{@x}"
```

```
[22:38:40 INF My.Foo.FooClient] HELLO WORLD
```

links

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/3.3.0-dev-00291
- https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/pull/281

Comment: And it has stable released just now!